# sending data between erlang and c++

Tags: c++, erlang

I am using a tcp connection to send data to a c++ server. I have read about ei library which when given a binary has a bunch of functions to get the decoded value out of the binary. Egs, ei_decode_string, ei_decode_long and others.

I am trying to do these simple things:
1. create a socket and connect to it.

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect({127,0,0,1}, 8986, []).
```

2. Use gen_tcp:send/2 to send data.

```
gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary("Stackoverflow")).
```

Therefore, I am sending a binary format of a string to the server.

My Server, C++ code, gets the data and I am trying to get whatever the client sends me over the socket using ei_decode_string like:

Ideally, when decoded I should get back the string, "Stackoverflow" since I told it to decode_as_string from the binary. Made sure I had enough space in the resulting buffer.

```
char *p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
int index = 0;
int decoded = ei_decode_string(buff, &index, p);
cout<<"The decoded value is "<<p<<endl;
```

I am not able to decode the string which I sent.! Am I missing something? How can I send data and decode it on the server side, if this is not the right approach.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: figured it out but that is just a tweek. I can see that on the server side, I am receiving an extra question mark(?) and if I pass the buffer skipping that charecter, ei_decode_string works fine. but not sure, why I am getting that extra question mark(?).

Comment: I suppose the same reason as `binary_to_list(term_to_binary("Stackoverflow"))` does not work as expected

Comment: For the sake of proper, clear answer: if one wants to convert a string into a binary representing characters of that string, one should use [`list_to_binary/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1). `term_to_binary` should be used when the recipient expects data in [Erlang external term format](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html).

Comment: Make sure you use gen_tcp:connect(SomeHost, 8986, [binary, {packet, 0}]). The packet option specifies how many bytes indicate the packet length, this could add the extra character that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

```
1> term_to_binary("Stackoverflow").
<<131,107,0,13,83,116,97,99,107,111,118,101,114,102,108,
  111,119>>
```

Here the first item in the binary is not the string as small integers, but a version number (131) as described in [External Term Format](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html). After that comes the terms each prefixed by a tag and then corresponding data. In this case tag 107 `STRING_EXT`, two bytes for length (13) and then 13 8bit integers, first one 83 corresponds to letter 'S' (83 in ascii).

To handle this binary correctly correctly, call to `ei_decode_version` has to be before `ei_decode_string`

> int ei_decode_version(const char *buf, int *index, int *version)
>
> This function decodes the version magic number for the erlang binary
>   term format. It must be the first token in a binary term.